# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions given by integrals

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, riemann-integration

If $f_n:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions converging uniformly to a function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, and also if each $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable over $[a,b]$ for any $0<a<b<\infty$, I know that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)dx = \int_a^bf(x)dx.
$$
Fixing a $a = a_0$, we can say that the sequence of functions $F_n(x) = \int_{a_0}^xf_n(t)dt$ converges to $F(x) = \int_{a_0}^xf(t)dt$. But is this converge uniform?

I'm tried to show that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence: given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $m,n>n_0$ implies $|\int_{a_0}^r f_m(x)dx - \int_{a_0}^rf_n(x)dx|<\epsilon$ for all $r>0$. But I don't know how to use the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ without losing the independence on the point of the domain. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For $n$ large $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then $|\int_{a}^{b}f_n-\int_{a}^{b}f|\leq |b-a|\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<|b-a|\epsilon$.

Comment: @logarithm But you have dependence on $b$ which is what I'm trying to fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the statement you're trying to prove is correct; the result does not hold on the unbounded interval $(0, \infty)$. If this interval was bounded, this result would hold, as you have already noted.

For a concrete example, consider $f(x) = x + 1$ and the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ defined by $$f_n(x) = x + \frac{n - 1}{n}.$$ Then clearly, $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$. On the other hand, we have $$\lvert F(x) - F_n(x) \rvert = \bigg\lvert \int_0^x f(t) \, dt - \int_0^x f_n(t) \, dt \bigg\rvert = \bigg\lvert \int_0^x \frac 1n \, dt \bigg\rvert = \frac xn$$ for all $n$, which is larger than any $\varepsilon > 0$ for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: I actually thought in using the statement to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$, and I thought that would be the way. So what I must use to conclude this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think my knowledge in real analysis is sufficiently grounded to answer your follow-up question. However, your expression above can be proved by showing that $\lim_{B\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^B f_n(x) \; dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{B\to\infty} \int_0^B f_n(x) \; dx$, since the left hand side of this equation is equal to $\lim_{B\to\infty} \int_0^B f(x) \; dx$. However, I'm not entirely sure whether the two limits can be interchanged.

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony: This answers the question you posted (+1).  Asking about conditions where $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is another question. Are you assuming that those improper integrals converge?  Even if they do, uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ is not sufficient. Take, for example, $f_n(x) = 1/n$ for $0\leqslant x \leqslant n$; $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x > n$.  Dominated convergence where there is an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leqslant g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming a $g$ with these conditions, but I yet don't know how to prove the equality. But I'll ask another question.