Equicontinuity of a set
this is an excercise in an old test from my course of analysis.
Let $\rho : \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty]$ continuos such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\rho(t)dt=1$. Let $f_n$ secuence of real functions, bounded and continuos that converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $F_n(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f_ n(t)\rho(t)dt$.
Is $E=\{F_n \space| \space n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ equicontinuos?
My (not) try:
As $f_n$ is bounded, there exist a $M_n>0$ such that $\|{f_n}(t)\|\leq M_n$. In order to show that E is equicontinuos for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$, consider $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$|F_n(x)-F_n(a)|=\left|\int_0^xf_n(t)\rho(t)dt-\int_0^af _n(t)\rho(t)dt\right|=\left|\int_a^xf_n(t)\rho(t)dt\right|\leq\int_a^x|f_n(t)\rho(t)|dt\leq M_n$$
I’m pretty sure that i’m in the wrong direction because i didn’t use the uniform convergence but i don see how to attack the problem instead, so if someone can give a me hint id appreciate it.

The uniform convergence guarantees a uniform bound on $|f_n(t)|$ for every $n$ and $t$, after that think of what happens to the integral of $\rho$ when the interval in which you integrate it gets small

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211687/uniform-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-given-by-integrals?rq=1 for a previous solution to a similar problem.

Since $\{f_n\}$ is bounded and uniformly convergent, it is uniformly bounded (e.g. see here), hence $|f_n(t)|\leq M$ for all $n,t$. Now following your idea, we get
$$|F_n(x)-F_n(a)|\leq\int_a^x|f_n(t)\rho(t)|dt\leq M\int_a^x\rho(t)dt.$$
Let $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\rho(t)dt$, then $G$ is continuous by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Moreover, since $\rho\geq0$, $G\in[0,1]$ is monotonically increasing, thus $G$ is uniformly continuous (because $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous if it is continuous, bounded and monotonic). Hence for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|G(x)-G(a)|<\varepsilon/M$ for all $|x-a|<\delta$, which implies
$$|F_n(x)-F_n(a)|\leq M|G(x)-G(a)|<\varepsilon$$
for all $|x-a|<\delta$ and this concludes the equicontinuity.

nice solution, thanks!
